# Group by multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: group-by

I have two queries:

```
SELECT  city, count(id) as num_of_applicants 
FROM(
    select distinct(students.id), city
    FROM STUDENTS INNER JOIN APPLICATIONS ON STUDENTS.ID = APPLICATIONS.STUDENT_ID
    WHERE APPLICATIONS.COLLEGE_ID = '28'
    ) AS derivedTable
GROUP BY city;

SELECT city, count(id) as num_of_accepted_applicants
 FROM
     (select applications.id, city FROM
     STUDENTS INNER JOIN APPLICATIONS ON STUDENTS.ID = APPLICATIONS.STUDENT_ID
     WHERE status = 'Accepted' and college_id = '28') as tbl
GROUP BY city
```

one give the number of applicants for each college and one give the number of accepted applicants in each college, but I want to get a result in on query (instead of) where the result is something like:
`city   |   number_of_applicants  | number_of_accepted_applicants`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify (*fyi: I didn't understand why you used the derived tables, you could have just put the COUNT and GROUP BY on the inner queries*) and combine the queries as this:

```
SELECT city
  , COUNT(*) AS num_of_applicants
  , SUM( CASE
            WHEN status = 'Accepted' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS num_of_accepted_applicants
FROM STUDENTS
JOIN APPLICATIONS 
  ON STUDENTS.ID = APPLICATIONS.STUDENT_ID
WHERE college_id='28'
GROUP BY city;
```

Another way is to continue with the technique of derived tables. Make each of your queries a derived table and JOIN on the city - but that would not perform as well.

Comment: I got this error: function if(boolean, integer, integer) does not exist

Comment: Sounds like a PostGreSQL error. Did you try this within MySQL?

Comment: no, I thought they have the same syntax in this case thats why I put mysql in the title. I am actually using postgresql

Comment: Different syntaxes - I changed the code from using an IF to CASE - which I think will work. I am not a PostGreSQL person, but this would be the general concept

Comment: I found a way on how to convert that "sum-if)" into postgresl function. thank you sooo much, but could you please explain to me the logic behind that (sum(if)), I was not able to understand the logic of that query, or if you have a link please send it to me

Comment: The logic is pretty simple: A new column is created. The column has a 1 whenever the status is 'Accepted', 0 otherwise. When you GROUP the rows, it adds that column's values which is essentially same as counting the 1's. _(If you still don't get it, try removing the GROUP BY, the COUNT and the SUM (but leave the CASE statement), then look at the results)_